# How can I copy files using the ansible.builtin.copy module and avoid conflicting file names?

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

I want files in the `src` directory to copy to the `dest` directory but I don't want the files with the same name to copy over. Does anyone know how I can do that?

```yaml
- name: Copy files but not the ones that have the same name
  copy:
    src:  <src_dir>
    dest: <dest_dir>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q: ***"Don't copy the files with the same name."***

A: Set the parameter [*force*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/copy_module.html#parameter-force) to *false*. Quoting

> If false, the file will only be transferred if the destination does not exist.

```yaml
    - copy:
        src: /tmp/test/src/
        dest: /tmp/test/dest/
        force: false
```

---

Example.

Given the files

```bash
shell> tree /tmp/test/
/tmp/test/
├── dest
│   └── a
└── src
    ├── a
    ├── b
    └── c

2 directories, 4 files
```

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/test/src/*
src
src
src
```

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/test/dest/*
dest
```

The playbook

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - copy:
        src: /tmp/test/src/
        dest: /tmp/test/dest/
        force: false
```

will copy the files *b* and *c* only because the file *a* exists

```bash
shell> tree /tmp/test/
/tmp/test/
├── dest
│   ├── a
│   ├── b
│   └── c
└── src
    ├── a
    ├── b
    └── c

2 directories, 6 files
```

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/test/dest/*
dest
src
src
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`backup`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/copy_module.html#parameter-backup) option of the `copy` module.

```yaml
- copy:
    src: foo
    dest: /tmp/bar
    backup: true
```

This will create multiple files, of which, the one with the name specified in `dest` parameters will be the one representing the last run of Ansible.

For example:

```bash
$ ls -l /tmp/
total 12
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root   150 Mar 20 16:30 bar
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root   127 Mar 20 16:20 bar.249.2023-03-20@16:20:44~
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root   148 Mar 20 16:20 bar.329.2023-03-20@16:30:17~
```